Jitterbit Vinyl app() function does not return the app I am in
I am using Vinyl now owned by Jitterbit and I need to dynamically pull the current app ID when processing a business rule. When I call the app() function that states it returns the app ID, it returns the app ID of Vinyl itself. I need the app inside of Vinyl. I can see the values in the database and they match the url when on the individual apps. Anyone have a solution?
I have tried calling app() and expected it to return my current app but it just returned the entire applications ID which I cannot imagine ever needing to call dynamically since it is a fixed variable. Only time I could see calling app() is to see which app is running inside of Vinyl. I have checked the official jitterbit documentation but it is useless for this.
